# Can't use jquery after loading it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading data.js into my a.html page.

In my data.js, i am checking if a.html has jquery and loading it if not. Right after loading jquery i am making an ajax call but i am getting

```
$ is not defined
```

exception.

Here is my data.js

```
if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
            var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
            jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
            jqTag.src = 'http://localhost:8001/jquery-min.js';
            headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
        }

        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
               $("#" + containerId).html(data);
            },
            error: function(e) {

               console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
```

From developer console, i can see jquery is loaded. I can see it in both Resources and head tag.

Comment: And in your developer console, do you get any errors ?

Comment: Your ajax call is being run before the jQuery file is loaded.

Comment: @adeneo i am getting $ is not defined error, it's already in question.

Comment: You should do the same to your Ajax script.

Comment: It's asynchronously pulling down the file. It's not loaded by the time you get to your `$.ajax` call. You can watch the `readyState` or `onload` event of the `script` element and add a callback.

Comment: Should be noted that the usual way of adding a jQuery fallback to local files is by adding `(window.jQuery)||document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8001/jquery-min.js"><\/script>');>` in the head

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery (and $ thus) isn't loaded yet when you make the AJAX call since you only just added the script tag to your DOM. After that it starts the downloading. Instead you should bind the onload event of script tag and perform the actions after it has been loaded.

Example

```
jqTag.onload = function() {
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
           $("#" + containerId).html(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {

           console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
}
jqTag.src = 'http://localhost:8001/jquery-min.js';
```

Comment: how can i understand it's loaded?

Answer (score -3):

change this Line :

`if(typeof jQuery=='undefined')`

to

```
if(typeof jQuery== undefined ) {
```

Comment: `typeof` always returns a string, so doing that the condition would never be true ?