# How to detect jquery is loaded when loading it dynamicly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load jquery to page if it's not loaded. I'll run some code right after loading it. With below code, i am trying to catch it when jquery is loaded.

My code loads jquery correctly but not raising onreadystatechange event.

```
if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'http://localhost:8001/jquery-min.js';
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);

    jqTag.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
            this.loadWidget(containerId);   
        }
    };
}
else {
    this.loadWidget(containerId);
}
```

How can i catch it when jquery is loaded?

Comment: Why not just `jqTag.onload = function() { ...`

Comment: @adeneo please post this as an answer, so i can accept it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use jquery after loading it dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867867/cant-use-jquery-after-loading-it-dynamically)

Comment: Sure, posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script tags have an `onload` event for when the script has loaded

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {

    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag   = document.createElement('script');

    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';

    jqTag.onload = function() {
        this.loadWidget(containerId);   
    }

    jqTag.src  = 'http://localhost:8001/jquery-min.js';
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);

} else {
    this.loadWidget(containerId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your code is way too complicated.

Why not do what HTML5 boilerplate has done:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

If the window.jQuery object isn't detected it elegantly fails over to write out the script tag to include it in native Javascript.  You can, of course change the path to whatever you want.

Hope this helps.